# After switching to SSL menu links are opening in new window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, ssl

Stumped! I added SSL to my site. Everything seems to be in order but now the menu items (using Uber Menu plugin with wordpress) open in a new window.

I've discovered two things. When this file which is loaded in the functions.php file is http vs. https the links open in the same window as desired, but it breaks some sliders I have on the homepage.

(https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js)

When changed to https - sliders work, but now links open in new window.

Looking for any help!

CODE of Functions File

```
   function modify_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 
'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.8.2');
        // wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

Website: https://www.sojournercenter.org/

EDIT: I've noticed something somewhere is adding the "_blank" tag to all my links when this file is running. But it does not seem to be that file, but another jquery file. At least I think!

Comment: your links href are defined with the attribute target="_blank", meaning they will open in a new window. try to use target="_self" or remove it altogether since _self is the default

Comment: Where would I change this? It seems to be affected by the js file is it in there somewhere? I'm familiar with _blank and _self but can't understand why after adding the ssl this would change.